# AutoCAD COM Application slows down after a specific amount of iterations

Tags: c#, com, autocad

I'm working with the AutoCAD COM library to move around blocks so they don't overlap. The way i'm doing it right now is move a selection set around in a circle trying to find an open space, if none was found it expands the circle.

The problem is that after the 387-388 step of this loop it slows down considerably. I added a stopwatch to see where the slowdown was appearing, but the exact location changes if I remove things. I actually removed everything I thought could be slowing it down and that didn't help either. So, at this point I really have no clue why the slow down is *consistently* happening.

Here is the code I believe is causing the slowdown, let me know if you need more info:

```
// Selection set
Int16[] filterCode = new Int16[] { 8 };
object[] filterValue = new object[] { LAYERNAME };
selectionSet.Select(AcSelect.acSelectionSetAll, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, filterCode, filterValue)

// This is how I grab the blocks
listOfEntities = new List<AcadEntity>();
foreach(AcadEntity entity in selectionSet)
{
    if(entity.ObjectName.Equals("AcDbBlockReference"))
    {
        AcadBlockReference block = entity as AcadBlockReference;
        if(block.Name.Equals(BLOCKNAME))
            listOfEntities.Add(entity);
    }
    else if(entity.ObjectName.Equals("AcDbText"))
    {
        listOfEntities.add(entity);
    }
}
```

Then I use a `foreach` loop to move through the entities in the list and call my function that finds the empty space.

```
if(listOfEntities.Count > 0)
{
    _thisDrawing.SendCommand("zoom extent ");

    foreach(AcadEntity entity in listOfEntities)
    {
        FindEmptySpace(entity);
    }
}
```

This is how I move the block around to find the empty space.

```
radius = (blockHeight > blockWidth ? blockHeight: blockWidth) / 10;

for(double distance = radius; ; distance += radius)
{
    angle = PIx2 / distance;

    for (double currentAngle = angle; currentAngle < PIx2; currentAngle += angle)
    {
         try
         {
             AcadSelectionSet spaceSelection;
             // This ends up being 387-388 every time the slow down starts.
             _totalSteps++;

             // The new location of the block
             newCenterLocation[0] = ((Math.Cos(currentAngle) * distance) + centerLocatoin[0]);
             newCenterLocation[1] = ((Math.Sin(currentAngle) * distance) + centerLocation[1]);

             // The new bounding box points
             newMaxExt[0] = newCenterLocation[0] + (blockWidth / 2);
             newMaxExt[1] = newCenterLocation[1] + (blockHeight / 2);
             newMinExt[0] = newMaxExt[0] - blockWidth;
             newMinExt[1] = newMinExt[1] - blockHeight;

             // Make sure the "SpaceSet" isn't already created.
             // I'm not sure if there is an easier way to do this.
             try
             {
                 _thisDrawing.SelectionSets.Item("SpaceSet").Delete();
             }
             catch
             {}

             spaceSelection = _thisDrawing.SelectionSets.Add("SpaceSet");

             block.Move(centerLocation, newCenterLocation);

             spaceSelection.Select(AcSelect.acSelectionSetCrossing, newMinExt, newMaxExt, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

             // This is '== 1' because I'm moving the block as well as the selectionset
             if(spaceSelection.Count == 1)
             {
                 spaceSelection.Clear();
                 // Found empty space
                 return;
             }

             spaceSelection.Clear();
             // Empty space wasn't found at this location, move block back.
             // I need to to this because it seems that the Move function moves
             // the blocks based on the difference between the two locations.
             block.Move(newCenterLoaction, centerLocation);
         }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure If I'm forgetting to do anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Also, I've tried using the 2002 and 2013 versions of the COM, not sure if there is a difference.

**UPDATE**: While working on the version problem I posted, I got the app to work on 2002. It never slows down while running on AutoCAD 2002. It's the exact same code, the only differences are the library I use and the version number (AutoCAD.Application.15 vs AutoCAD.Application.19). So, there's that.

Comment: There isn't any way to look at code like this and make any guesses as to why how such a large and complex application like AutoCAD will slow down.  Remove all interop calls and verify it runs consistently.  I'm sure it will.  And that's where it about ends as far as what you can do.  Only Autodesk support can get you further, although I seriously doubt that they won't do anything but dismiss it as "by design".

Comment: What version of autocad are you running?  What is the purpose of your task, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: And can you put the code you are using to iterate through the SS in your post?

Comment: @TraeMoore Right now I'm working on 2013 but it also needs to work on 2002, so I can't use the .Net api unless I'm want to write ObjectARX as well. I will post some more code in a bit.

Comment: You could always use lisp... Just saying..

Comment: Yeah, normally I'm not a huge fan of LISP automation, but what you're trying to do would make way more sense in LISP.  Especially if you want this to work in 2002 in a single solution.  However if you really do want to continue using this in .NET, can't you leverage the Bounds of the entity you're working with to check overlaps?

Comment: Also in terms of performance, having Try/Catch inside loops is a good way to kill speed at runtime.  For the selection set, check if it exists first and if it does then delete it.  That way you don't need to catch any exceptions.  I also don't see the need for the Try block surrounding everything in the loop.  Just check your variables for null before you use them, and let AutoCAD catch the errors on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

One tip, rather than use SendCommand, use this for zooming extents (from AutoCAD .NET developer help):

```
// Zoom to the extents of the current space
Zoom(new Point3d(), new Point3d(), new Point3d(), 1.01075);
```

Comment: As I'm using the COM interface, I don't think I have access to that exact Zoom command. I tried using _acadApp.ZoomExtents() method instead, but it just throws an exception without any information.